# Matlab- Given matrix X with xi samples, y binary column vector, and a vector w plot all these into 3d graph

Tags: matlab, plot, machine-learning, linear-algebra

I have started to learn Machine Learning, and programming in matlab.
I want to plot a matrix sized m*d where d=3 and m are the number of points.
with y binary vector I'd like to color each point with blue/red.
and plot a plane which is described with the vertical vector to it w.

The problem I trying to solve is to give some kind of visual representation of the data and the linear predictor.

All I know is how to single points with plot3, but no any number of points.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the plane go through the origin?

Answer (score 2):

Plot the points using `scatter3()`

```
scatter3(X(y,1),X(y,2),X(y,3),'filled','fillcolor','red');
hold on;
scatter3(X(~y,1),X(~y,2),X(~y,3),'filled','fillcolor','blue');
```

or using `plot3()`

```
plot(X(y,1),X(y,2),X(y,3),' o','MarkerEdgeColor','red','MarkerFaceColor','red');
hold on;
plot(X(~y,1),X(~y,2),X(~y,3),' o','MarkerEdgeColor','blue','MarkerFaceColor','blue');
```

There are a few ways to plot a plane. As long as `w(3)` isn't very close to `0` then the following will work okay. I'm assuming your plane is defined by `x'*w+b=0` where `b` is a scalar and `w` and `x` are column vectors.

```
x1min = min(X(:,1)); x2min = min(X(:,2));
x1max = max(X(:,1)); x2max = max(X(:,2));
[x1,x2] = meshgrid(linspace(x1min,x1max,20), linspace(x2min, x2max, 20));
x3 = -(w(1)*x1 + w(2)*x2 + b)/w(3);
surf(x1,x2,x3,'FaceColor',[0.6,0.6,0.6],'FaceAlpha',0.7,'EdgeColor',[0.4,0.4,0.4],'EdgeAlpha',0.4);
xlabel('x_1'); ylabel('x_2'); zlabel('x_3'); axis('vis3d');
```

---

#### Resulting plot

[image]